# removing one property of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that looks like this.

```
{
par1: 'par1value',
par2: 'par2value',
par3: 'par3value'
};
```

I want to remove the property called `par1` and save it separately so it looks like this

```
var par1 = 'par1value';

{
par2: 'par2value',
par3: 'par3value'
};
```

Can someone suggest a nice way to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Get the property:

```
var value = obj.par1;
```

Remove the value from the object:

```
delete obj.par1;
```

More detail about delete can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object).

Answer (score 4):

It has been answered already here: [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

basically,

```
var parobject = {
par1: 'par1value',
par2: 'par2value',
par3: 'par3value'
};

var par1 = object.par1;

delete parobject.par1;
```

Addition: The delete operator is described in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/special_operators/delete_operator